# Append "tweet this" button to blockquotes with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Updated:**

I'd like to append a self made "tweet this" button after blockquotes with jQuery. I figured out the following three steps are necesarry (some are already resolved thanks to the stackoverflow community):

1. *[resolved]* appending *anything* to the blockquote
2. *[resolved]* appending a working twitter share link to the blockquote
3. making sure it works with multiple blockquotes

The code I'm using at the moment is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var completeurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + window.location.search;
completeurl = encodeURIComponent(completeurl);
var twshare = "https://twitter.com/share?url=" + completeurl;
var bq = $( "blockquote" ).text()

$("blockquote").append("<a href='" + twshare + "&text=" + bq + "'>Click to tweet</a>");   
</script>
```

So the current state is: I'm stuck at #3, making it work with multiple blockquotes per page. Ideally it wouldn't be necesarry to manually assign IDs or something similar. So fully automated one @tweet this" button per blockquote. Is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: `append` doesn't add an element *after*, but as a child *inside*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing adequate markup, it is difficult to point where the problem is.

However, it works just fine.

See this fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/JvT7h/2/**

```
$("blockquote").append("<a href='http://twitter.com'>Click to tweet</a>");
```

*Aside*: `append` doesn't add an element *after*, but as a child *inside*.

**Update**:

As per your comments you need to customize the `anchor` link to be appended to multiple `blockquotes` depending upon the text of each `blockquote`.

See this updated demo fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/JvT7h/3/**

*JQuery*:

```
$("blockquote").each(function(){
    var $link = $("<a />"), 
        linkText = "Click to tweet",
        url = twshare + "&text=" + $(this).text();
    $link.attr("href", url);
    $link.text(linkText);
    $(this).append($link);
});
```

You need to iterate over all `blockquotes` and then use `$(this)` to append the customized anchor.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me finding my mistake for #1: I had placed it too early in the code, moving it further down helped. Can't give the example because it's rather complex, but basically the content didn't exist where I placed the code (some WordPress php stuff was going on after that). I'll update my original question. Would upvote your answer but can't do this yet...

Comment: @stnwbr: there you go. updated the answer to customize links for all/multiple blockquotes.

Comment: Great, wouldn't have figured that out on my own! Thanks a lot @abhitalks